# HTTP_HOST с WWW, когда в адресной строке введено без WWW

Tags: redirect, .htaccess, php

Здравствуйте,
Наткнулся на проблему, настраиваю редирект с WWW на без WWW, но переменная HTTP_HOST всегда с WWW. И поэтому если настраивать редирект с WWW на без WWW идет циклический редирект, а если делать наоборот - ничего не происходит.

В чем можеть быть проблема того, что HTTP_HOST всегда с WWW ?
Спасибо.

Если не видно картинку: [скриншот](http://prntscr.com/3ykxje)

Еще скриншоты:
[Скриншот без WWW](http://prntscr.com/3ylmuh)
[Скриншот c WWW](http://prntscr.com/3ylngt)

[image]

Comment: То, что указано в настройках сервера, попадет в `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`  .
То, что запросил браузер пользователя, попадет в `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']`.

От этого и плясать. `HTTP_HOST` в этом плане лучше вообще не смотреть, там *позволено* валяться чему угодно.

Comment: да, но в моем случаи и SERVER_NAME и HTTP_HOST идут с WWW, даже когда в браузерной строке указано без WWW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.ru/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Этот вариант не подходит?

А делать с помощью php это полное извращение.

Comment: **.htaccess**

Comment: Опечатался, спасибо!

Comment: Сам так делаю, вроде работает. Только вопросик, может надо www\\.example\\.ru или и без слешей пашет (со слешами работает точно)?

Comment: @MDJHD, в этом конкретном случае может и будет работать. Но если вы  не понимаете разницу между `\.` и просто точкой, то этот пробел в знаниях лучше ликвидировать :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответы, проблемы были в том что хостеры неправильно настроили VirtualHost